# how to select mutiple column match with a single value other column values be null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table value like

```
masterid   dateorder    Ist      IInd    IIIrd  IVth    Vth     VIth
------------------------------------------------------------------------
08mcaao1     1          MC1701   MC1702  MC1703 Mc1704  Mc1705  Mc1701
08mcaao1     2          MC1701   MC1702  MC1703 Mc1703  Mc1705  Mc1702 
08mcaao1     3          MC1701   MC1703  MC1703 Mc1704  Mc1705  Mc1701
```

if i'm select this table based on column value like MC1701

the result must be this form

```
masterid dateorder    Ist     IInd   IIIrd    IVth   Vth     VIth 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
08mcaao1    1         MC1701    -     -        -      -      Mc1701 
08mcaao1    2         MC1701    -     -        -      -      - 
08mcaao1    3         MC1701    -     -        -      -      Mc1701
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) on fields Ist, IInd, IIIrd, IVth ,Vth, VIth to compare it against your criteria.  If it matches with your criteria display the value otherwise display `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @param as nvarchar(100)
set @param = 'whatever'
select
... 
case when Ist = @param then Ist else '-' end 'Ist'
...
where Ist = @param or ...
```